# How many dice are used when shooting double-barreled firearms?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, attack-roll, firearms

The double-barreled pistol enables a special standard action to shoot both barrels at once by pulling both triggers with -4 penalty.

Is it a single attack die, functioning similarly to the Manyshot feat (the first attack)? Or two dice, one for each barrel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Pathfinder Roleplaying Game: Ultimate Equipment, pg.43](https://www.aonprd.com/EquipmentWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Double-barreled%20musket)

> If both barrels are fired at once, they must both target the same
>   creature or object, and the gun becomes wildly inaccurate, taking a –4
>   penalty **on each shot**.

So by using this special standard action you roll a separate attack for each barrel, each taking the -4 penalty - similar to the [Rapid Shot](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Rapid%20Shot) feat.